# Negative values on unsigned int with union all

Tags: mysql, union

When I do union all on queries with unsigned int fields, it returns negative results.

Can someone explain this behavior to me ?
How can I have real ids in "ticketIn" ?

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `group` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `prev_group` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_mod` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

-- data
INSERT INTO history
    (`ticket`, `group`, `prev_group`, `date_mod`)
VALUES
    (2201100001, 53042, 0, '2022-01-10 00:04:05.000'),
    (2201100002, 53042, 0, '2022-01-10 00:10:01.000'),
    (2201100003, 53042, 0, '2022-01-10 00:10:02.000'),
    (2201100003, 52973, 53042, '2022-01-10 00:11:25.000'),
    (2201100004, 53043, 0, '2022-01-10 00:54:41.000'),
    (2201100004, 52972, 53043, '2022-01-10 01:08:20.000')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SET
  @s = CAST('2022-01-10' AS DATE);
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`history_out`.date_mod, '%Y-%m-%d') AS "thedate",
  `history_out`.group,
  `history_out`.ticket AS "ticketOut",
  NULL AS "ticketIn",
  `history_out`.id
FROM
  history `history_out`
WHERE
  (`history_out`.prev_group IN (53042))
  AND (`history_out`.date_mod >= @s)
UNION
ALL
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`history_in`.date_mod, '%Y-%m-%d') AS "thedate",
  `history_in`.group,
  NULL AS "ticketOut",
  `history_in`.ticket AS "ticketIn",
  `history_in`.id
FROM
  history `history_in`
WHERE
  (`history_in`.group IN (53042))
  AND (`history_in`.date_mod >= @s);
```

| thedate | group | ticketOut | ticketIn | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-10 | 52973 | 2201100003 |  | 4 |
| 2022-01-10 | 53042 |  | -2093867295 | 1 |
| 2022-01-10 | 53042 |  | -2093867294 | 2 |
| 2022-01-10 | 53042 |  | -2093867293 | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wsJs5DRYddoRautLxHwYjg/0)

Comment: Actually, this appends only in MySQL <= 5.7 and MariaDb <= 10.2 (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&rdbms2=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=7d93a7aa633173e26da2a8bd8ecf1628)

Comment: `-2093867293` smells like a large (> 2^31) `INT UNSIGNED` being displayed as `SIGNED`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`history_out`.date_mod, '%Y-%m-%d') AS "thedate",
  `history_out`.group,
  `history_out`.ticket AS "ticketOut",
  cast(NULL as unsigned int) AS "ticketIn",
  `history_out`.id
FROM
  history `history_out`
WHERE
  (`history_out`.prev_group IN (53042))
  AND (`history_out`.date_mod >= @s)
UNION
ALL
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(`history_in`.date_mod, '%Y-%m-%d') AS "thedate",
  `history_in`.group,
  NULL AS "ticketOut",
  `history_in`.ticket AS "ticketIn",
  `history_in`.id
FROM
  history `history_in`
WHERE
  (`history_in`.group IN (53042))
  AND (`history_in`.date_mod >= @s);
```

[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3cb367f74ef955f0421d2db40fa1a5c3)

PS. when I was working with RDBMS, the first select in a union decided the format of the columns.  MySQL 5.7 may be as old.